# Why [wordpress] tag on WordPress Answers?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there any special reason for its existence?
I can't think of any use for it. What do you think? Am I missing something?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress

Comment: By the way there are also many questions tagged `wordress-3`, `wordpress-3.0.1` for no reason really. Harder to deal with because version tag can make sense for version-specific question, but then it gets into auto-suggest and people plaster it over anything.

Comment: I can imagine this situation with 3.0 vs 3.1 tags. But 3.0.1 was just a minor maintenance release. I wonder if any of the tagged questions are really 3.0.1 specific. Most of them seems to be referring to 3.0 awesomeness.

Comment: Great question. I'm going to rant for a second, but what are people thinking when they tag with *"wordpress?!?"* Clearly they were not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excellent point -- I deleted the tag and added it to the tag blacklist.

(we also ban the "apple" tag on apple.se and the "android" tag on android.se for similar reasons of redundancy)

However, there are now 23 questions tagged [untagged](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) which means wordpress was the only tag they had. We'll need some help retagging these.

Comment: I've added tags to all of them. As a result my name is now plastered all over the homepage, I apologize for that.

Comment: What about wordpress-X versions tags (as per my comment on question above)? Any rules from other sites in network that apply?

Comment: @rarst that is more of an open issue. They do it on http://askubuntu.com but I am not sure I like it there, and it's still being discussed on their meta. I personally would only tag with version when the thing being discussed is CRITICALLY associated with that version, otherwise you risk "every question has a version number" which I think is a very bad pattern to be in.

Comment: Wait … your reputation score is just 131 – and you are allowed to delete tags? That’s not fair! :)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood maybe `wordpress-*` tag can be banned in favor of `version-*` or `v*` ? That way it won't pollute auto-suggest for people who type `wordpress` there and people who are actively looking to tag with version will get just that suggested.

Comment: @rarst I support that but it has to be clear that versions are only required when the thing being discussed is *EXTREMELY* version-centric.. otherwise no version # necessary (and version-* is my pick of your tag namings because it'll be easiest to search for)

Comment: @Rarst: One of the earliest Meta discussions was about this, I created [a new answer out of this comment thread](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tag-for-wordpress-3/340#340) so more people see it and we can vote on it.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - *BIG* +1 on the *EXTREMELY* version centric. My view is that it's so likely to be abused that it might be better just not to have version specific tags?

Comment: @mike I support that, because a lot of users in my experience can get a particular kind of OCD when they see version tags.. and they want to version tag everything.

Comment: @Jeff I just noticed another question with the `wordpress` tag and found several more. All of them were migrated here from other sites. Does that mean blacklisted tags aren't removed when a question is migrated? (Should I add that as a feature request/bug somewhere?)