# Mass-rename [wordpress-(number)] to [version-(number)]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We all seem to agree that the `[wordpress-*]` tag to indicate a version number is a [bad](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/420/why-are-there-minor-revision-version-numbers-in-tags) [thing](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tag-for-wordpress-3). Version tags should be used very sparingly, but as long as we don't have good guidelines on when to use them and when not, it is hard to do a cleanup. Because the `[wordpress-]` prefix makes them very visible, they keep popping up for new questions.

I propose the moderators or site owners do a mass-renaming of all `[wordpress-*]` to their `[version-*]` equivalents, so they are moved to the side. If possible, the `[wordpress-(number)]` pattern should be made illegal (maybe hard to do, because there are other `[wordpress-*]` tags that are still useful).

I expect this will greatly reduce the number of new questions with version tags. It would then be more manageable to set up a feed for the `[version-*]` tag and retag any new question that uses it. The existing pile of questions with a version tag would then still exist, but it would not encourage new users to use the tag too.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: @Arlen: Do what automatically? Renaming the current tags? This is a simple operation for the site admins, but they only do it if there is a clear request from the community, hence this question. Re-tag incorrect new questions? You need a human to decide whether the tag should be used, and what other tags to add.

Comment: Yeah, renaming current tags.

Comment: I would support this. Also: *major* version numbers only. No minor releases ("WordPress X.Y.Z") or *pseudo*-releases ("WordPress X").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed, sort of. We prefer the simpler form of

[3.0](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3.0)

and

[3.0.4](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3.0.4)

etc. FYI, the wiki summary for these tags *absolutely should* contain a disclaimer like

> Should only be used on questions that are absolutely specific to a particular version of WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

Bump. Wait, make that ♦bump♦.

Situation with [wordpress-3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-3) gets worse by day, likely because of auto-complete. [wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) was [banned](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338/why-wordpress-tag-on-wordpress-answers) and auto-complete moved on.

My opinion is we really **need `wordpress-[number]` tags banned** or there will be no end to this. People who need to tag with specific version can do that with `version-[number]`, which is way less likely to be propagated by auto-complete unnecessarily.

Comment: I completely agree. I retag around 3 or 4 questions a day with wordpress-[number] but it's impossible to catch all of them.